# Pandas select preferred value from one of two columns to make a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns of "complementary" data. For any given row, there are 3 possibilities:

1) Column `A` has a non-null value, and column B has a null value, `NaN`, that I want to replace with the non-null value from column `A`.
2) Column `A` has a null value, `NaN`, that I want to replace with the non-null value from column `B`.
3) Both columns `A` and `B` have null values, `NaN`, which means I'll keep `NaN` as the value for that row.

Here's a simplified version of my DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['keep1', np.nan, np.nan, 'keep4', np.nan], 
                   'B' : [np.nan, 'keep2', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

I was thinking that as an intermediate step, I'd create a new column `C` with the entries I need:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['keep1', np.nan, np.nan, 'keep4', np.nan], 
                    'B' : [np.nan, 'keep2', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                    'C' : ['keep1', 'keep2', np.nan, 'keep4', np.nan]}
```

Then I'd drop the first two rows `A` and `B`:

```
df_final = df2.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1)
```

My actual DataFrame has hundreds of rows, and I've tried several approaches (boolean filters, looping through the DataFrame using `iterrows`, using `DataFrame.where()`) without success. I'd think this would be a simple problem, but I'm not seeing it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combine_first()` to fill the gaps in A from B:

```
df1['C'] = df1['A'].combine_first(df1['B'])
#0    keep1
#1    keep2
#2      NaN
#3    keep4
#4      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a really handy method.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values from `A` by `B` values:

```
df1['C'] = df1.A.fillna(df1.B)
print (df1)
      A      B      C
0  keep1    NaN  keep1
1    NaN  keep2  keep2
2    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  keep4    NaN  keep4
4    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

For avoid `drop` is possible use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns:

```
df1['C'] = df1.pop('A').fillna(df1.pop('B'))
print (df1)
       C
0  keep1
1  keep2
2    NaN
3  keep4
4    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to know about the `.pop` option to avoid the `.drop` step. It's more efficient, but the drawback is that it changes the original DataFrame. The choice depends on what's more important. Thanks again!